# Convert CityGML model to CityJson file

Tags: json, github, gis, qgis, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I need help in converting **CityGML model to CityJson file** using `Citygml4j/`Citygml-tools` as I need to visualize the CityGML model in the *Qgis Software*. The tutorial that I get from CityJson website is to simple for student like me. I hopefully any one of you can help to step by step the solution of converting CityGML to CityJson. I sincerely appreciate any of your help. Thank you.

https://www.cityjson.org/tutorials/conversion/
https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-3d-city-models-in-qgis-46347a638760

Comment: why not just display the CityGML in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to its readme file in their github repo, it is basically:

```
citygml-tools to-cityjson /path/to/your/CityGML.gml
```

considering that you're in an unix system and opened your terminal at the package folder.

in windows it should be:

```
citygml-tools.exe to-cityjson your_CityGML.gml
```

considering that you're in the package folder and also the citygml file